# `learnr` and `gradethis` code boxes do not run after the second opening

Tags: r, r-markdown, learnr

I coauthor a teaching package depending on learnr that offers tutorials for students enrolled in our course. We are encountering problems when running the tutorials.

Install mypackage depending on learnr and gradethis
restart R
open any tutorial: it works fine.
close the tutorial (in both from browser or from the console)
open the same or a new tutorial: CODE BOXES show output directly and the user cannot interact with the tutorial any longer.
In order to explore the origin of the problem

- I have restarted R.
- I have installed the latest `learnr` from GitHub: remotes::install_github("rstudio/learnr")
- I have installed the latest `gradethis` from GitHub: remotes::install_github("rstudio/gradethis")
- I have restarted R again
- run two replicable Examples:

  - run learnr::run_tutorial("ex-data-basics", "learnr") SAME PROBLEM AS ABOVE
  - run learnr::run_tutorial("ex-data-summarise", "learnr") SAME PROBLEM AS ABOVE

**System details**

These are my system details, but we tried with more than one machine consistently getting the same error.
Output of `sessioninfo::session_info()`:

```
- Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_Netherlands.1252    
 ctype    English_Netherlands.1252    
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2021-10-13                  

- Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 package        * version     date       lib
 assertthat       0.2.1       2019-03-21 [1]
 backports        1.2.1       2020-12-09 [1]
 broom            0.7.9.9000  2021-08-19 [1]
 bslib            0.3.1       2021-10-06 [1]
 cachem           1.0.6       2021-08-19 [1]
 cellranger       1.1.0       2016-07-27 [1]
 checkmate        2.0.0       2020-02-06 [1]
 cli              3.0.1       2021-07-17 [1]
 coda             0.19-4      2020-09-30 [1]
 colorspace       2.0-2       2021-06-24 [1]
 crayon           1.4.1       2021-02-08 [1]
 curl             4.3.2       2021-06-23 [1]
 DBI              1.1.1       2021-01-15 [1]
 dbplyr           2.1.1       2021-04-06 [1]
 digest           0.6.28      2021-09-23 [1]
 dplyr          * 1.0.7       2021-06-18 [1]
 ellipsis         0.3.2       2021-04-29 [1]
 evaluate         0.14        2019-05-28 [1]
 fansi            0.5.0       2021-05-25 [1]
 fastmap          1.1.0       2021-01-25 [1]
 forcats        * 0.5.1       2021-01-27 [1]
 fs               1.5.0       2020-07-31 [1]
 generics         0.1.0       2020-10-31 [1]
 ggplot2        * 3.3.5       2021-06-25 [1]
 glue             1.4.2       2020-08-27 [1]
 gradethis      * 0.2.4.9000  2021-10-13 [1]
 gtable           0.3.0       2019-03-25 [1]
 haven            2.4.3       2021-08-04 [1]
 highr            0.9         2021-04-16 [1]
 hms              1.1.0       2021-05-17 [1]
 htmltools        0.5.2       2021-08-25 [1]
 htmlwidgets      1.5.4       2021-09-08 [1]
 httpuv           1.6.3       2021-09-09 [1]
 httr             1.4.2       2020-07-20 [1]
 igraph           1.2.6       2020-10-06 [1]
 intergraph       2.0-2       2016-12-05 [1]
 jquerylib        0.1.4       2021-04-26 [1]
 jsonlite         1.7.2       2020-12-09 [1]
 knitr            1.36        2021-09-29 [1]
 later            1.3.0       2021-08-18 [1]
 lattice          0.20-44     2021-05-02 [1]
 learnr         * 0.10.1.9016 2021-10-13 [1]
 lifecycle        1.0.1       2021-09-24 [1]
 lubridate        1.8.0       2021-10-07 [1]
 magrittr         2.0.1       2020-11-17 [1]
 markdown         1.1         2019-08-07 [1]
 mime             0.12        2021-09-28 [1]
 modelr           0.1.8       2020-05-19 [1]
 munsell          0.5.0       2018-06-12 [1]
 network          1.17.1      2021-06-14 [1]
 nycflights13   * 1.0.2       2021-04-12 [1]
 pillar           1.6.3       2021-09-26 [1]
 pkgconfig        2.0.3       2019-09-22 [1]
 promises         1.2.0.1     2021-02-11 [1]
 purrr          * 0.3.4       2020-04-17 [1]
 R6               2.5.1       2021-08-19 [1]
 rappdirs         0.3.3       2021-01-31 [1]
 Rcpp             1.0.7       2021-07-07 [1]
 readr          * 2.0.1       2021-08-10 [1]
 readxl           1.3.1       2019-03-13 [1]
 renv             0.14.0      2021-07-21 [1]
 reprex           2.0.1       2021-08-05 [1]
 rlang            0.4.11      2021-04-30 [1]
 rmarkdown        2.11        2021-09-14 [1]
 rprojroot        2.0.2       2020-11-15 [1]
 rstudioapi       0.13        2020-11-12 [1]
 rvest            1.0.1       2021-07-26 [1]
 sass             0.4.0       2021-05-12 [1]
 scales           1.1.1       2020-05-11 [1]
 sessioninfo      1.1.1       2018-11-05 [1]
 shiny          * 1.7.1       2021-10-02 [1]
 SNA4DS           0.11.1      2021-10-13 [1]
 statnet.common   4.5.0       2021-06-05 [1]
 stringi          1.7.5       2021-10-04 [1]
 stringr        * 1.4.0       2019-02-10 [1]
 tibble         * 3.1.5       2021-09-30 [1]
 tidyr          * 1.1.3       2021-03-03 [1]
 tidyselect       1.1.1       2021-04-30 [1]
 tidyverse      * 1.3.1       2021-04-15 [1]
 tzdb             0.1.2       2021-07-20 [1]
 utf8             1.2.2       2021-07-24 [1]
 vctrs            0.3.8       2021-04-29 [1]
 withr            2.4.2       2021-04-18 [1]
 xaringan         0.22        2021-06-23 [1]
 xaringanExtra    0.5.4       2021-08-23 [1]
 xfun             0.26        2021-09-14 [1]
 xml2             1.3.2       2020-04-23 [1]
 xtable           1.8-4       2019-04-21 [1]
 yaml             2.2.1       2020-02-01 [1]
 source                                  
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 Github (tidymodels/broom@3177beb)       
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 Github (rstudio/gradethis@26741c6)      
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 Github (rstudio/learnr@b000739)         
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 Github (SNAnalyst/SNA4DS@ddd6da1)       
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 Github (gadenbuie/xaringanExtra@5e2d80b)
 CRAN (R 4.1.1)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          
 CRAN (R 4.1.0)                          

[1] C:/R/R-4.1.1/library
```

**Describe the problem in detail**

After installation, any tutorial correctly runs only one time. After the first run, tutorials are no longer interactive. They directly show output.

image one: tutorial opened for the first time.

image two: tutorial opened for the second time. No longer interactive.

image 1:

[image]

image 2:
[image]

Comment: It turns out that it works fine if the `learnr` library is attached before running the tutorial. However, since the tutorials are meant to be in a package depending on `learnr` (not always, but they can), it would be nice if the  `learnr` developers would enable the usage without having the learnr package attached.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is provided by this [pull request](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/pull/599)

Comment: @Phil the question was intended for the Rstudio developers. In fact, it has been addressed by one of them at Rstudio/learnr on Github. This is the reason why having the keyword `Rstudio` was helpful.